# Einstein Bot Builder Error when Build Model clicked: 'Your Model Requires Attention.' How to troubleshoot?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, chat, bots, einstein-chatbot

[image: BB error when Build Model clicked]

Unable to Build Model. I have adequate intents and utterances.

Comment: This issue can be resolved by disabling/re-enabling the Bot.

For that, you have to reach salesforce support. Raise a case and our team will assist you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I deleted duplicate utterances, there were a lot.
2. After, a new error appeared highlighting intents that had < 20 utterances. After I inserted enough utterances, I was able to build model.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused due to duplicate utterances. Please check the utterance which you are currently adding to the new dialog is already present in the existing dialogs or intent sets.

1. If Present, then delete the utterance from there and add to new dialog and build the model.
2. Best practice is to follow the rules provided by the salesforce to add utterances.

Comment: This appears to be functionally similar to the existing answer which was given 1.5 years ago. Similar answers can be fine, but there should be something meaningful and distinct to differentiate them.